Proposition 10.13, "Attaching a disk".
The excerpt below is taken from J. Lees "Introduction to Topological Manifolds".


In the absolutely last sentence of the second picture, the claim is that $\overline{b} \cdot c \cdot b$ is a generator of $\pi_1(D\setminus\{z\},v)$. I feel like there is some missing detail not spelled out here (although it is more likely that I am being stupid). Why exactly does this hold? By assumption we know that $c:I \to \text{Int}(D)\setminus\{z\}$ is a representative element for a generator of $\pi_1(\text{Int}(D)\setminus\{z\},p)$ and that $b:I \to D$ is a path in $D$ from $p$ to $v$. I believe we can view $c$ as a path in $D\setminus\{z\}$ by the inclusion $\iota: \text{Int}(D)\setminus\{z\} \to D\setminus\{z\}$. But does this inclusion somehow force the induced homomorphism $\iota_*:\pi_1(\text{Int}(D)\setminus\{z\},p) \to \pi_1(D\setminus\{z\},p)$ to take $[c]$ to a generator of $\pi_1(D\setminus\{z\},p)$ (here I note that $D\setminus\{z\}$ is homotopy-equivalent to $S^1$ and hence it is motivated to speak of a single generator of $\pi_1(D\setminus\{z\},p)$)?
I think the idea is then that $\overline{b} \cdot c \cdot b$ is a representative element for the image of $[c] \in \pi_1(D\setminus\{z\},p)$ under the change-of-basepoint isomorphism $\Phi_b:\pi_1(D\setminus\{z\},p) \to \pi_1(D\setminus\{z\},v)$.

We have that
\begin{align*}
\text{Int}(D) &\approx \mathbb{B}^2\\
\implies \text{Int}(D)\setminus\{z\} &\approx \mathbb{B}^2\setminus\{0\}\\
&\approx \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}\\
&\simeq S^1
\end{align*}
where the homotopy equivalence in the last step is induced by the strong deformation retraction of $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$ to $S^1$ (see Prop. 7.37 in Lee).
This implies that
\begin{align*}
\pi_1(\text{Int}(D)\setminus\{z\},p) &\cong \pi_1(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\})\\
&\cong \pi_1(S^1),
\end{align*}
where the last isomorphism follows from the fact that homotopy-equivalences induces isomorphism of fundamental groups.
Furthermore, we have that
\begin{align*}
D &\approx \overline{\mathbb{B}}^2\\
\implies D\setminus\{z\} &\approx \overline{\mathbb{B}}^2 \setminus\{0\}\\
&\simeq S^1,
\end{align*}
which in turn means that
\begin{align*}
\pi_1(D\setminus\{z\},p) &\cong \pi_1(\overline{\mathbb{B}}^2\setminus\{0\})\\
&\cong \pi_1(S^1).
\end{align*}
It follows that $\pi_1(\text{Int}(D)\setminus\{z\}) \cong \pi_1(D\setminus\{z\})$.
This atleast shows that their fundamental groups must be isomorphic.
